# Admob load only test ads

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin.forms

I tried to add ads in my app but unfortunately it loads only test!
I used this library https://github.com/marcojak/MTAdmob so my MinActivity.cs

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    MobileAds.Initialize(this, "here is my app id");
    LoadApplication(new App());
}
```

AndroidMAndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.samplemtadmob">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <application android:label="SampleMTAdmob.Android">
      <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="my app-id"/>
      <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
      <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

And i tried to load reward video with

```
CrossMTAdmob.Current.LoadRewardedVideo("ca-app-pub-2774421889203876/4315339018");
```

Google also send my email 
`Your account is approved
Congratulations! We've verified your account information and your ad serving is enabled.`
But  my app loads only test ads.

Comment: When apps are newly registered with AdMob, it takes some time and a few ads requests to allow inventory to build. Please note that test ads operate through the same channels as live ads. Being able to return a test ad ensures that your application is communicating properly with our network. Be patience it will work after some days.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Thanks for answer!I will be patient

Comment: I will post it as answer with more details , could you accept it ? Which will help more people :)

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT ok nice

Comment: Does it work now ?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT only send request but nothing else.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Should it uploaded to Google Play Store and only test ads load

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT i saw that ads load only on emulator

Comment: You could post your problem at https://support.google.com/admob/#topic=7383088